# en el orden de jerarquia matematica me da 410 y en la compilacion del codigo me da 400 cual debe ser el error?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
 main() 
{ 
  double  x = ( 4 * 5 * ( 7 + ( 9 * 3 / ( 2 ) ) ) ) ;
  cout<<"el resultado de x es: "<<x;// el resultado es 400

  getch();  
}
```

Comment: x = ( 4 * 5 * ( 7 + ( 9 * 3 / ( 2 ) ) ) ) 
x=(4*5*(7+(9*3/2)))
x=(4*5*(7+(27/2)))
x=(4*5*(7+(13.5)))
x=(4*5*(7+13.5))
x=(4*5*(20.5))
x=(4*5*20.5)
x=(20*20.5) x=(410) x=410

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todas tus operaciones son con enteros, con lo cual todos los resultados son enteros.

Eso significa, que al dividir `27 / 2` obtendrás `13` (`13.5` no es un entero). Así:

- 9 * 3 = 27
- 27 / 2 = 13
- 7 + 13 = 20
- 20 * 20 = 400

Lo más sencillo es convertir algún número (lo más interno que tengas), a punto flotante, eso hace que la aritmética pase a ser con punto flotante.

Por ejemplo, pasas `3` a `3.0`, y te queda:

- 9 * 3.0 = 27.0
- 27.0 / 2 = 13.5
- 7 + 13.5 = 20.5
- 20 * 20.5 = 410.0

Otra opción es asegurarte de que los divisores son siempre números flotantes, ya que la fuente del error es el usar la división entera en vez de la división en plunto flotante.

Comment: gracias solo cambie el dividendo 3 por el 3.0 en el código y se resolvió el problema, gracias buen aporte.